# Linq Update a row if new rows are inserted in another table

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 4 tables here, I am trying to update last entry row when new rows are added in another table using linq

**CustomerTable**:

```
CustomerId Name   EmailId
-------------------------
1          Paul   r@r.com
2          John   J@j.com
```

Below table I am assigning points for each LoyatyType

**LoyaltyPointTable**:

```
LoyaltyPointsId LoyaltyType     Points
---------------------------------------
1               Registration       10
2               Loginstatus         1
3               Downloading        10
4               Redemming           1
5               Sharing            20
6               Refer              10
```

**LoyaltyDetailsTable**:

```
 LoyaltyDetailsId LoyaltyPointsId CustomerId Dates
 -------------------------------------------------
  1                    1            1       2015-01-22 
  2                    2            1       2015-01-22 
  3                    3            2       2015-01-22
  4                    3            1       2015-01-22 
  5                    4            1       2015-01-22
  6                    4            1       2015-01-24  
  7                    2            1       2015-01-24  // here one new row is added based on LoginStatus
```

he has done Login one time , so his LoginStatus Point is 1 now I want update this point  in another table below

**Expected output:**

**PriceClaimTable**

```
PriceClaimId CustomerId PriceId  Current Points

1               2         22          150
2               1         23          200 // here update the last row of CustomerId as 231 
                                      //based on every new entry on LoyaltyDetailsTable
```

Say if he  Logins again 200 + 1 = 201
Then he is Downloading 201 + 10 = 211
Then he does sharing 211+20 = 231

can i use sql triggers in Linq and find a solution for this ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i am using Sqlserver 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use can use `triggers` for doing this job. You can look [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-SQL-Server) for writing one.

Comment: can we use triggers in Linq or is there any other method

Comment: I dont have much idea about Linq.. but AFAIK we can do that with Linq-to-SQL provider

Comment: thank you so much karthik, i used triggers as you said and finally it worked , sorry for accepting your answer so late.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a view on the LoyaltyDetailsTable joined to the LoyaltyPointTable that sums LoyaltyPointTable.Points across each customer e.g. something like (depending on your dialect of SQL)

```
CREATE VIEW PriceClaimView
AS

SELECT CustomerId, SUM(LPT.Points) AS CurrentPoints
FROM LoyaltyDetailsTable LDT INNER JOIN LoyaltyPointTable LPT ON    LDT.LoyaltyPointsId = LPT.LoyaltyPointsId
GROUP BY CustomerId
```

Comment: This has the advantage that if you need to remove a LoyaltyDetailsTable entry for some reason the View is automatically corrected next time it is read

Comment: i get error as : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'BEGIN', and one more question, using this can i update the PriceClaimTable row from 200 to 231 based on changes in LoyaltyDetailsTable ? i am using Sqlserver 2012

Comment: Which DBMS uses a `begin .. end` when creating a **view**?

Comment: If I were you I would not try to persist the output of the VIEW in the PriceClaimTable. It is 'derived data' and, unless you have very demanding performance constraints it is best to calculate derived data as you need it.

Comment: I've removed the BEGIN/END above

Answer (score 1):

1, at your data engine

you could use a  trigger

2, your program

you could code a mechanism.

Usually trihger hurt performance, i will use plan B

Comment: hi, i also like code mechanism but how can i achieve this in Linq, i mean find changes in another table and update a table row

Comment: thank you for plan A,  @karthik also mentioned to go with trigger, plan B i dont know how to do, anyway works fine.